# jquerymobile popup function is not working in the onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-body">
        <a href="#transitionExample" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">
          Pop Up
        </a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample">This is a POP UP.</div>
        <a href=# onClick="$('transitionExample').popup('open')"
        data-rel="popup">OpenPopUp</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click on Button It Works, but if I use Javascript method .popup('open'), nothing happens. Popup is not showed.

What is happening? 
I use, JqueryMobile 1.2.0  and JQuery 1.8.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('transitionExample').popup('open')
```

should be

```
$('#transitionExample').popup('open')
```

for more info see: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

then you better bind your link in the .ready(), you should try to avoid `Javascript` code in the `DOM` for better maintainability.

```
 <a href='#' id='myButton' data-rel="popup">OpenPopUp</a>
```

and between your `<script></script>` tags

```
$(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        $('#transitionExample').popup('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this thread whilst trying to find the reason for precisely the same behavior - clicking on a data-rel='popup' link was working but the popup() method was not showing anything.  After much frustration I eventually discovered that the issue was down to the fact that I had coded

```
$('#popupid').popup(open)
```

NO QUOTES!  No one complained - Chrome did not throw up an error but the popup call did nothing.

Hopefully, this will help someone else one day.